# Error de logueo con laravel en hosting

Tags: laravel, hosting

He logrado subir mi proyecto a un hosting compartido y lo que hice es:
Editar `AppSevicesProvider`:

```
public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind('path.public',function(){
        return'/home/autorepu/public_html';
    });
}
```

Editar `public_html\index.php`:

```
<?php

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));
require __DIR__.'/../elrayo/vendor/autoload.php';//elrayo=nombre de la carpeta contenedora del proyecto
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../elrayo/bootstrap/app.php';

 $app->bind('path.public', function() {
    return __DIR__;
});


$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Y por su puesto el `.env`...(no lo publicare)

### Aqui se viene lo bueno

Al abrir mi mipagina.com, me muestra la vista del login, lo cual esta correcto, pero al momento de querer loguearme con las credenciales correctas este me vuelve a redirigir al login sin mostrarme ningun tipo de error. **NOTA: El login funciona correctamente en local**

Mi login controller esta asi:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RedirectsUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use RedirectsUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        return view('login');
    }

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validateLogin($request);
        if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
            $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);
            return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
        }
        if ($this->attemptLogin($request)) {
            return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
        }
        $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);
        return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
    }

    protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            $this->username() => 'required', 'password' => 'required',
        ]);
    }

    protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
    {
        return $this->guard()->attempt(
            $this->credentials($request), $request->has('remember')
        );
    }

    protected function credentials(Request $request)
    {
        return $request->only($this->username(), 'password');
    }

    protected function sendLoginResponse(Request $request)
    {
        $request->session()->regenerate();
        $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);
        return $this->authenticated($request, $this->guard()->user());
    }

    protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {
        //dd($user); me muestra el usuario correcto, pero la redireccion no funciona
        return redirect()->route('sucursal.index');
    }

    protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
    {
        return redirect()->back()
            ->withInput($request->only($this->username(), 'remember'))
            ->withErrors([
                $this->username() => Lang::get('auth.failed'),
            ]);
    }
    public function username()
    {
        return 'email';
    }
    public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        $this->guard()->logout();
        $request->session()->flush();
        $request->session()->regenerate();
        return redirect('/');
    }
    protected function guard()
    {
        return Auth::guard();
    }
}
```

La ruta `sucursal.index` esta protegida con el `middleware` **auth**, y cuando hago la prueba de Auth::user(), este siempre es null;

> cual seria el problema al momento de loguearse?

Comment: Qué middlewares son los que estás utilizando? Y cómo tienes configurado tus guards en config/auth.php?

Comment: En los logs de laravel no te arroja nada?

Comment: @L.Flor el unico middleware es el auth. El guard deberia ser `web`, y que hago Auth::guard().

Comment: Me refería a los middlewares registrados en tu Kernel. Y has intentado haciendo $request->user() y también obtienes null?